# jquery find specific columns in a table column in tbody element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, jquery-selectors

```
var html_table =
    "<table class='table'>" +
    "<thead>" +
    "<tr><th>#</th><th>First</th><th>Second</th><th>Third</th><th>Fourth</th><th>Fifth</th></tr></thead>" +
    "<tbody>" +
    "<tr><td ></td><td></td><td>Pitt</td><td>35</td><td>New York</td><td>USA</td></tr>" +
    "</tbody>" +
    "</table>";

var $html_table = $(html_table);
var first_column= $html_table.find('???');
var second_column= $html_table.find('???');
```

So i have above table in javascript and using jquery to get the first and third columns. But find() method doesn't seem to be flexible enough to get first and third column inside tbody element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get access to all td of column with next code:

```
var columnNumber = 0; //first column
$.each($html_table.find("tr"), function(){
  var tdOfCurrentColumn = $(this).children().eq(columnNumber);
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the column using .eq function.

```
$html_table.find('tbody tr td').eq(0) // First element
$html_table.find('tbody tr td').eq(2) // third element
```

In eq function, use the index, that starting with 0.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your table has `id="table"`.  You can do this:

```
var first_column = $('#table:first-child');
var second_column = $('#table:nth-child(2)');
```

I haven't tried this out, but it should work.  Feel free to utilize css3 selectors in all their magnificent glory.

Comment: but i have defined table in javascript only in variable html_table . so #table may not be available to jquery selector, i have to find some jquery method i believe

Answer (score 0):

From Chris, I think it is easier using the CSS3 selectors.

```
var first_column= $("tbody td:nth-child(1)",$html_table)
var second_column=  $("tbody td:nth-child(2)",$html_table)
```

check this out.
https://jsfiddle.net/nvg4f2at/1/